# Control Linux Application Launch/Licensing

Tags: linux, licensing, launch

I need to employ some sort of licensing on some Linux applications that I don't have access to their code base.

What I'm thinking is having a separate process read the license key and check for the availability of that application. I would then need to ensure that process is run during every invocation of the respected application. Is there some feature of Linux that can assist in this? For example something like the sudoers file in which I detect what user and what application is trying to be launched, and if a combination is met, run the license process check first.

Or can I do something like not allow the user to launch the (command-line) application by itself, and force them to pipe it to my license process as so:

/usr/bin/tm | license_process    // whereas '/usr/bin/tm' would fail on its own

Answer (score 2):

> I need to employ some sort of licensing on some Linux applications

Please note that license checks will generally cost you *way* more (in support and administration) than they are worth: anybody who wants to bypass the check and has a modicum of skill will do so, and will *not* pay for the license if he can't anyway (that is, by *not* implementing a licensing scheme you are generally *not* leaving any money on the table).

> that I don't have access to their code base.

That makes your task pretty much impossible: the only *effective* copy-protection schemes require that you rebuild your entire application, and make it check the license in so many distinct places that the would be attacker gets bored and goes away. You can read about such schemes [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1886411794).

> I'm thinking is having a separate process read the license key and check for the availability of that application.

Any such scheme will be bypassed in under 5 minutes by someone skilled with `strace` and `gdb`. Don't waste your time.

Answer (score -1):

You could write a wrapper binary that does the checks, and then link in the real application as part of that binary, using some dlsym tricks you may be able to call the real main function from the wrapper main function.

IDEA

1. read up on ELF-hacking: http://www.linuxforums.org/articles/understanding-elf-using-readelf-and-objdump_125.html
2. use ld to rename the main function of the program you want to protect access to. http://fixunix.com/aix/399546-renaming-symbol.html
3. write a wrapper that does the checks and uses dlopen and dlsym to call the real main.
4. link together real application with your wrapper, as one binary.

Now you have an application that has your custom checks that are somewhat hard to break, but not impossible.

I have not tested this, don't have the time, but sort of fun experiment.

Comment: Doing this is most likely a copyright violation on the "real" application if you don't have the explicit consent of the copyright holder.

Comment: "use ld to rename main function ..." -- first "ld" can't do anything to an already-linked executable, and second, renaming "main" would be completely pointless: its address is already recorded as the call target that `_start` will call.

Comment: Somewhat tired when I wrote that about ld, what I am trying to do is to link the application together with a piece of code that will somehow do the checks, I do have to agree with you(@EmployedRussian) that most ways are pointless against a attacker that are skilled in programming. but it is better than any type of separate process. @EmployedRussian what do think about using objcopy to include the real application into the wrapper and somehow changing the instruction pointer if the checks does not fail, else exit.