# Place in ELF to write foreign data

Tags: linux, elf

I'm trying to create a program that is monitoring its own checksum. For this purpose I'm trying to find a place where I can put checksum inside the binary. After checking the layout and examining some compiled executables I found several of those:

- Padding fields inside some of the headers. These are skipped on loading, but I'm hesitant to use those since they are reserved;
- Some field of SHT_NULL section header. If this header is unused, I can fit checksum inside one of its fields. Problem is - I'm not sure if it's used or unused when loading. And also I'm not sure if it's always present in the compiled binary;
- Create some global array, find .data section with it and write checksum here. Right now I'm not sure if it's possible to find pointer to the start of the array just by looking into the binary;
- Put my data in the end of the file. Probably the easiest, but I don't really want to change the size of the binary.

Can one of the first three places be used for my purpose? I mean, theoretically, I can write data wherever I want, but are those places adequate? Maybe I'm missing some other possible places in the binary. Or should I fall back to just writing checksum in the end of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every approach except this one:

> Create some global array, find .data section with it and write checksum here.

invokes undefined behavior of some sort. These approaches may appear to work, until they don't.

> I'm not sure if it's possible to find pointer to the start of the array just by looking into the binary

It is definitely *easy* to find the location of that array in an unstripped binary -- read the symbol table, find the name of your symbol and its address will be *right there*.

You could also place that array in a separate section using `__attribute__((section(...)))`, and find that section from section headers even if the symbols are stripped.

That said:

1. changing `.data` contents will change the checksum (unless you also exclude the array from your checksum computation) and
2. you are probably trying to implement some kind of copy protection, in which case your efforts are [likely to be in vain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8950818/50617).

Comment: Will the new section with array be optimized away if I turned up optimization and stripped the binary? And does linker takes into account such attributes in this case?

Comment: @AndrewGuschin You'll probably want to reference the new section from code to prevent the linker from removing it. See KamilCuk's answer. But stripping and optimization are irrelevant, and if you don't compile with `-fdata-sections` and have other used data section or code in the same translation unit, then you don't need to worry about this at all.

Answer (score 2):

> Create some global array, find .data section with it and write checksum here. Right now I'm not sure if it's possible to find pointer to the start of the array just by looking into the binary;

That's very simple, just do not put in .data section, create your own section.

```
$ cat file.c
#include <stdio.h>
__attribute__((__section__("_mydata"),__used__)) volatile char mydata[1024];
int main() {
        printf("%s\n", mydata);
}
$ gcc file.c
$ objcopy --update-section _mydata=<(echo -n 'hello') ./a.out && ./a.out
hello
$ objcopy --update-section _mydata=<(echo -n 'world') ./a.out && ./a.out
world
```